# When I load a shell at startup in my init file, why do I get 26 shell prompts?

Tags: emacs, initialization, aquamacs

When I load a shell at startup - just using (shell) in my .emacs file - there are always 26 shell prompts "bash-3.2$ bash-3.2$ bash-3.2$...".  Why is that happening?  This is happening the same way in emacs on a terminal and aquamacs.

Comment: Try putting a `set -x` at the beginning of your .bash_profile or .bashrc. and a `set +x` at the end of it (assuming you're using bash). This might help you figure out what's being called.

Comment: 26 reminds me 26 letters of Alphabet. Check something if related.

Comment: it turns out I have 26 commands in my .bashrc.  I wish there were a way to load the shell after loading the .bashrc file, but maybe the shell is what's causing the .bashrc to load.

Comment: ok, scratch that.  I started killing things in my .bashrc and the number of shelll prompts increased to 43!  Now it's 43 each time.  What is going on here?

Comment: Post the contents of your `.bashrc` and of your `.emacs`. Does this happen if you start Emacs with `emacs -q`?

Comment: if I start emacs with -q it doesn't load the init file, so there's no shell.  If I disable my .bashrc file completely I get one shell prompt, so I'm considering .bashrc the culprit.  There's nothing complicated in my .bashrc, just a bunch of aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use binary search to narrow things down to find the culprit. Sounds complicated, but it is very fast.

Just comment out half of your init file (`.emacs`), then a quarter, then an eighth, etc. until you know precisely what part causes the problem.  Use any of the keys/commands that comment/uncomment the region to do this.  (I use `comment-region`, which I bind to <kbd>C-M-;</kbd>.

Comment: if I create an entirely new .emacs file which contains only (shell), I still get 26 shell prompts.  I am now thinking this is caused by my .bashrc getting loaded and firing a shell prompt for each command.